# What is a production in the context of the C Programming language?

Tags: c, parsing

In Appendix A of The C Programming Language, Second Edition, by Kernighan and Ritchie, the word production is mentioned:

> This manual describes the C language specified by the draft submitted
> to ANSI on 31 October, 1988, for approval as ``American Standard for
> Information Systems - programming Language C, X3.159-1989.'' The
> manual is an interpretation of the proposed standard, not the standard
> itself, although care has been taken to make it a reliable guide to
> the language. For the most part, this document follows the broad
> outline of the standard, which in turn follows that of the first
> edition of this book, although the organization differs in detail.
> Except for renaming a few **productions**, and not formalizing the
> definitions of the lexical tokens or the preprocessor, the grammar
> given here for the language proper is equivalent to that of the
> standard.

I can't however seem to make out what it actually means. My guess is that it refers to the value of a key in the grammar section:

> translation-unit:
> external-declaration translation-unit
> external-declaration

The following piece from section A 13 should hint at what the writer means but I can't seem to figure it out by myself as I miss some essential terminology:

> The grammar has **undefined terminal symbols** integer-constant,
> character-constant, floating- constant, identifier, string, and
> enumeration-constant; the typewriter style words and symbols are
> **terminals given literally**. This grammar can be transformed
> mechanically into input acceptable for an automatic parser-generator.
> Besides adding whatever syntactic marking is used to indicate
> alternatives in productions, it is necessary to expand the ``one of''
> constructions, and (depending on the rules of the parser-generator) **to
> duplicate each production with an opt symbol, once with the symbol and
> once without.** With one further change, namely deleting the production
> typedef-name: identifier and making typedef-name a terminal symbol,
> this grammar is acceptable to the YACC parser-generator. **It has only
> one conflict, generated by the if-else ambiguity.**

I don't know either what the embolden words/sentences mean. Can someone give me an insight?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_(computer_science)

Comment: Hey @Mat, I'm having some troubles understanding the broad concept. Could you perhaps try explaining it a little?

Comment: It is the usual terminology for formal grammars/parsing-type things in computer science. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar might be more approachable. BTW the whole things you quote are mostly irrelevant except if you plan on writing a (conforming) C parser - which would not be a great idea if you don't have any experience with parsing in general.

Comment: Do you also by any chance know which productions are renamed @Mat?

Comment: @Mat I'm a 42 student and I'm trying to make my first Anki deck on the reference manual of the C Programming Language with the reason to become more knowledgeable of the language.

Comment: Then I'd advise you to skip over the formal grammar part until you are more familiar with that domain in general - if you're interested in that specifically you'd better start with more "regular" languages (e.g. Lisp, Ocaml, maybe Haskel). The grammar of a language isn't particularly interesting, focus more on the semantics, the memory model, the execution model.

Comment: I will try to keep it short, but it does provide my brain with a lot of dopamine, so a short skim doesn't hurt anyone :)

Comment: @Mat What do you then think of the following paragraph of the reference manual?
"A.2.5 Constants
There are several kinds of constants. Each has a data type; Par.A.4.2 discusses the basic types:
constant:
integer-constant
character-constant
floating-constant
enumeration-constant"
It does make sense to know what you're looking at right? I was also watching an interview with Brian, and he said the manual was intended to be used by starting to read the reference manual. Who am I to argue against his advice?

Comment: I didn't say don't read the book. I said don't get hung up on the formal grammar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In computer science, formal grammars are described using production rules. For example, a rule of the form:

> *P* → xyz

says the symbol *P* may be replaced by the symbols xyz, and a rule of the form

> *Q* → a*P* | b*P*

says the symbol *Q* may be replaced by the symbol a and the symbol *P* or by the symbol b and the symbol *P*.

The formal grammar designates a start symbol, such as *Q*, and says which symbols are nonterminal symbols (placeholders that do not appear in the final string) and which are terminal symbols (that may appear in the final string). If *Q* is the start symbol for the grammar with the two rules above, then these rules describe a grammar that contains two strings, axyz and bxyz, because those are the only two strings that can be made with those rules. The set of strings a grammar can produce is called its language.

λ is commonly used the mean an empty string, one with no symbols.

This grammar with nonterminal symbol *S*, terminal symbols a and b, and start symbol *S*:

> *S* → a*S*bb | λ

can produce the empty string by replacing *S* with the empty string, or it can produce abb by replacing *S* with a*S*bb and then the new *S* with the empty string, or it can produce aabbbb by replacing *S* with a*S*bb and then replacing the new *S* with a*S*bb, yielding aa*S*bbbb, and then replacing *S* with the empty string, yielding aabbbb. We can see the language of this grammar is the set of all strings containing some number of a characters (possibly zero) followed by twice as many b characters.

The C standard defines the C language using a formal grammar (with some qualifications and modifications in English). For example, it contains this production (where it uses “:” instead of the “→” I used above and uses separate lines instead of “|” to indicate a choice):

> *statement*:
>         *labeled-statement*
>         *compound-statement*
>         *expression-statement*
>         *selection-statement*
>         *iteration-statement*
>         *jump-statement*

Regarding the other terminology you marked in bold:

> undefined terminal symbols integer-constant,…

The C grammar given in *The C Programming Language* appears to be a partial grammar, leaving *integer-constant* as an undefined symbol, and hence acting as a terminal symbol. In the official ANSI C 1990 standard, it is a defined non-terminal in the official ANSI C 1990 standard.

> … the typewriter style words and symbols are terminals given literally.

This is clearer in the original, where the fonts used make it evident the “typewriter” style is a fixed-width font:

> … the `typewriter` style words and symbols are terminals given literally.

This, with its preceding text, means that, in the grammar, words in italic, like *declaration*, are non-terminal symbols of the grammar that “become something else” by productions of the grammar, while words in the “typewriter” font, like `typedef`, are terminal symbols and they are symbols for the literal characters in their names; `typedef` in the grammar means the characters t, y, p, e, d, e, and f in the source code.

> …to duplicate each production with an opt symbol, once with the symbol and once without…

The standard uses a subscript “opt”, like this:

> *P*: *Q* *R*<sub>opt</sub>

to mean that *R* is optional. Formally, this is actually two rules:

> *P* → *Q* *R*
> *P* → *Q*

meaning there is a rule that replaces *P* with *Q* *R* and a rule that replaces *P* with *Q*, and either may be used. Hence, the *R* is optional. Using the “opt” subscript is just a different way of writing the rules.

> … this grammar is acceptable to the YACC parser-generator. It has only one conflict, generated by the if-else ambiguity.

In computer science theory, a parser is software that checks whether a string is in a language. (In practice, it often does other useful things at the same time, like assigning “meaning” to the string by interpreting parts of it as numbers, parts as variables, and so on.) YACC is software that reads a specification of a grammar and produces source code for a parser for the language the grammar describes.

The type of parser that YACC generates requires deciding which production will be applied as each token is read. A conflict occurs when the grammar is inadequate determine which production to apply. In the C formal grammar, `if (x) if (y) S1 else S2` can be produced in two ways, one that associates `else S2` with the first `if` and one that associates `else S2` with the second `if`. This has to be resolved by adding information to the grammar; YACC is told to associate the `else S2` with the most recent `if` that does not currently have an `else`.

Comment: In my own words: Does this mean that production rule works a bit like an expansion?

Comment: @SaladinAfoh: Sort of, but grammar rules are not instructions to replace things; they are available options for replacing things. Something else has to make the choice about which rules to use. Until one is used to parsing theory, they can feel a bit backwards. When we parse a string, we look at the string and figure out backwards which rules are used to construct it from the start symbol, rather than taking the start symbol and choosing which rules to use forwards to replace things.

Comment: The quotes in the OP are from Appendix A of the 2nd edition of *The C Programming Language*, by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie; which should be cited correctly, and moreover should be read in context. "The grammar" in the text "The grammar has undefined terminal symbols" (A.13) refers to the grammar collected below that paragraph, as is made clear in the preceding paragraph. That grammar does not include lexical definitions since it was intended to be used in Yacc, which doesn't contain lexical definitions, only declarations. (The declarations need to be added for use with Yacc )

Comment: Yacc does not have a mechanism to describe the literal text corresponding to a terminal symbol. It 9nly has terminal symbols; the correspondence with actual text is contained in a separate lexical scanner. In a Yacc grammar, the keyword `for` would have to be written as something like `TOKEN_FOR`. That has little expository value, and K&R instead opted for typography to distinguish literal tokens like `for` from symbolic terminals such as *identifier*.

Comment: A Yacc grammar does not distinguish lexically between non-terminals and terminals. Semantically, a non-terminal is a symbol with a definition; a terminal is a symbol without a definition. (That is, an undefined symbol.) However, partly to avoid errors and partly to simplify grammar processing, Yacc insists that identifiers used to name terminals be declared before use with a `%token` declaration. Hence, Yacc can assume that an identifier not previously used in the grammar names a non-terminal.

Comment: (Some parser generators, such as ANTLR, do distinguish lexically; in ANTLR, a terminal's identifier must start with a capital letter while a non-terminal must start with a lower-case letter. That's good style for grammars IMHO but not a Yacc rule.)

Comment: Eric, one other thing: an ambiguity always produces a parsing table conflict, but not every conflict is an ambiguity. A conflict simply means that the parser can't tell which action to take based on the next input token. It's quite possible that the grammar is unambiguous, but the parser can't know which possibility will work without examining more of the input. When K&R say that the grammar has only one conflict, they are guaranteeing not just that the grammar is otherwise unambiguous, but also that parsing decisions can always be made immediately.

Comment: @rici: Thanks, updated. I might have to review the type of grammar YACC parses to do a better job—Feel free to update the answer if you like.

Answer (score 2):

A "symbol" is an element of a grammar.

E.g. in the section you quoted:

> *translation-unit*:
>       *external-declaration translation-unit external-declaration*

All four are symbols.

A "production" explains what a symbol consists of. Your quote is a single production that states that a *translation-unit* consists of three things in order: *external-declaration*, then *translation-unit*, then *external-declaration*.

---

A "terminal" symbol is a symbol that doesn't have any other symbols in its definition.

E.g. your `translation-unit` is not terminal, but this one is:

> *digit*: one of
>       `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9`

It's moot if the individual digits are terminals, or if the whole *"digit"* is terminal; probably the former.

Those are also "given literally", meaning the digits are actually spelled in the standard.

And here's a terminal not given literally:

> *basic-c-char*:
>       any member of the translation character set except the U+0027 apostrophe, U+005c reverse solidus, or new-line character

Notice how they didn't spell every possible character, since there are too many of them, and instead provided a plain text description.

---

An "undefined" terminal is just a terminal that wasn't explained/defined, making the grammar technically incomplete. If they call *"integer-constant"* an undefined terminal, it means their grammar fails to include `integer-constant: blah blah`.

---

> to duplicate each production with an opt symbol, once with the symbol and once without

Consider:

> *foo*:
>       `x`<sub>opt</sub>   `y`

Here *foo* is either `x` or `x y`.

They're suggesting an alternative way to spell the same thing, without using "opt":

> *foo*:
>       `y`
>       `x` `y`

---

> It has only one conflict, generated by the if-else ambiguity.

Parsing a program is done by starting with a single symbol, and figuring out which productions transform it to the text you're trying to parse.

If there's more than one sequence of productions that does it, the grammar is "ambiguous".

Comment: In my own words: Does opt mean otpional? 
Terminal means "end" and has nothing to do with actual terminals on my computer :)

Comment: Can you perhaps explain why they chose to ommit the production rule of for example an integer-constant?

Comment: @SaladinAfoh *"Does opt mean otpional?"* Yep. "Terminal" means "last", i.e. no more productions can be applied to it. *"why they chose to ommit the production rule"* Unsure. Maybe they explained what an "integer-constant" is in plain english.